# What's the conventional way to indicate an error inside defmacro?

Tags: error-handling, clojure, compiler-errors, macros

What is the conventional, well-behaved way for a macro to indicate that it's been passed invalid arguments?

```
(defmacro defthisthing [name & definitions] . . .)
```

I'm writing a macro right now to accept a whole bunch of definitions. If the same thing gets defined twice, the macro should complain. Similarly, if one of the definitions uses a term that's not defined elsewhere in the same macro invocation, the macro should complain, hopefully with line and column numbers so the programmer can see exactly where the error is.

I'm currently thinking that throwing an exception makes the most sense, because invalid macro arguments are in fact a compilation error. Everything should shut down no differently than if the compiler found unbalanced parentheses.

If that's correct, what is the conventional exception to throw? And how do you include the filename and line number of the offending snippet of code?

And if that's not correct, what is the more Clojurely approach?

Comment: This question seems to call for opinions since words as _conventional_ or _Clojurely_ indicate. This can spawn answers based purely on opinions that hold little technical value (_"I like to do it the `foo` way"_...). Could you please [edit] your question to focus more on the technical aspect of what you want to achieve? For example: _"How to report invalid argument passing from inside a macro?_"

Comment: It's no problem to think of _how_ to report an error in a macro—I can think of many ways. I want to know the _conventional_ way to do it in Clojure.

Answer (score 6):

Throwing exceptions sounds fine. I just checked the Clojure source and this is how it is done there:

[`(defmacro let ...)`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.7.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L4301) calls [`(defmacro assert-args ...)`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.7.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L1718), which throws exceptions if the arguments don’t meet their requirements.